# Is there any way to predefine a string in vb6?

Tags: string, vb6, predefined-variables

I was trying someting like:

```
Dim experiment As String = "Predefined experiment string.."
```

but sadly its not working so is there any way to predefine a string with a similar way in vb6?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For a *constant* string:

```
const experiment As String = "Predefined experiment string.."
```

At the top of a module/class/form with an access modifier for the corresponding scope, or in a routine as a local.

For strings with variable content you cannot declare and assign on the same line, you can however:

```
Dim experiment As String: experiment = "Predefined experiment string.."
```

Answer (score 3):

You are doing two things in a single statement: declaring a variable **and** initializing it.

In VB6 you have to do this in separate steps:

```
Dim experiment As String 
experiment = "Predefined experiment string.."
```